# Is it possible to get the age of a Facebook Page using their APIs?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I would like to find out when a Facebook Page was initially started.

I can access the Page's data through Facebook's REST API or Graph API and I can ask the Page's admin user to grant additional permissions if necessary.

Is the Page's start date available? Which methods of the API should I use for this? Which permissions are needed to get this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official documentation here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page
there is not a method to retrive when the page was initially started.

You may try to retrive all the posts and look at the oldest one! (using pagename/feed for the page, in case you are using Graph API).

Comment: Looking at the oldest post seems a bit hackish, but it may be the only way to go. Thanks.